# Marine Arena: Turn money into damage in late game

Tags: starcraft-2

I think I can master the early game pretty well now in Marine Arena, but I get into trouble in the endgame. Often I engage the enemy with my army, and we both lose most of our troops. Suddenly I have a lot of resources from the battle (1500 - 2000), but almost no units, except the ones that recently spawned. Now the enemy can just come into my base and crush me (the one I just fought with a couple of their leftover units, or worse, a third enemy).

- Upgrading units in the short term seems a waste as I have so few.
- Buying a hero takes too long (and I also might not have hero upgrades yet).
- Drop marines seems viable, but if I go for teched mercs, they're weaker than the enemies'.
- If I manage to buy an extra savior, I might surprise them, but that seems a waste if they're attacking me with just a handful of units. Also, it's hard to get if you don't have map control.
- Defensive structures seem useless against late game units.

Often people just camp around in their base, and wait for someone else to make the first move and lose. This sort of gameplay undermines the game and is not fun so I'd like to apply a strategy that is more participatory.

How I can quickly turn my surplus money into dps in the late game or is this even possible?

Comment: Are you recruiting while the engagement is being fought? Not familiar with custom maps, but it's something you should do in general, if you're somewhat skilled.

Comment: The thing with marine arena is that you don't recruit troops, they constantly spawn. You get minerals (bounty) for each unit you kill. The key is to kill many enemy units without loosing too many of your own, and then to upgrade your units with the money. You still have to research upgrades, chronoboost your buildings, etc., while fighting.

Comment: @jdm the thing I've always done which worked decent is trying to cut people off.  Take the high ground when people are fighting just in their entrance.  If your marines have enough range they can fire down without getting hurt too badly.  Or try to ambush someone whose already getting attacked (hitting them while they are down) or cutting out retreat paths.  Its a difficult game at times.  I've always favored marine upgrades but end game if you are lacking marines they are pointless.

Comment: I see this question getting close votes and poor answers. Based on its wording, this question seems to be asking rather open-ended strategy while at the same time, is simply asking if there are mechanics in this game mode to quickly convert money to DPS while late game. The existence or absence of such mechanics would be fairly acceptable objective answers. Perhaps rephrasing the question to more clearly ask for objective responses would help. Removing "Any idea" from the question body will help clarify objectivity.

Answer (score -1):

A lot of people use cracklings to overwhelm any ground unit, and they usually use them to exterminate all Terran ground units. I suggest you only try firebats, wraiths, zealots and zerglings themselves. During the game your opponents might tend to use marauders mostly, I usually use zerglings and firebats etcetera.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of what to do with late-game resources, though.